# Black Body Radiation of a Home

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

If there is a home which is far away from all other buildings, what is the heat transfer due to radiation at night?

Is the governing equation this : $\sigma\times(T_{\text{home}}^4 - T_{\text{space}}^4)$?

Does the home radiate to the atmosphere?  To space? To both?  I was wondering if perhaps the real equation is that it radiates to space and to the atmosphere at fractions related to the transmissivity and emissivity of those two bodies.

It seems like using the temperature of space or the atmosphere should lead to very high heat losses if those equations worked as I'm asking.  The losses would be much higher than what actually seems to be happening.

Thanks for helping me understand!

Comment: This is very complicated question but it goes with T^4 and it depends on the emissivity of the home (very hard to model.) and it is radiated outwards in all direction in 4Pi radians.

Comment: What is $T_{\rm home}$ defined to be?

Answer (score 1):

The equation is roughly correct, if you assume no losses due to conduction (e.g. into the ground) or convection, however:

$T_{\rm home}$ would be the *effective* temperature of the outside of the house. The whole idea of insulation is to make $T_{\rm home}$ much lower than the interior temperature when it's cold outside.

Secondly, the other term would be $T_{\rm space}$ if your house was in space (and shielded from the Sun). In practice your house is absorbing radiation coming from the ground and from clouds, nearby trees etc. You would need to use some average temperature that has been appropriately weighted for the solid angle subtended by the various radiation sources.